# Create new Outlook Mail Item event VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, email, events, outlook-addin

I am trying to catch the event when the user clicks on the New Mail button for writing a new mail. Any suggestions on what that is called? I have been looking everywhere for it but everything is directly me to the read mail option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new Outlook project Visual Studio creates the `FirstOutlookAddIn` project and opens the `ThisAddIn` code file in the editor.

Declare a field named inspectors in the `ThisAddIn` class

```
Private WithEvents inspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
```

Replace the `ThisAddIn_Startup` method with the following code

```
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    inspectors = Me.Application.Inspectors
End Sub
```

In the `ThisAddIn` code file, add the following code to the `ThisAddIn` class

This code defines an event handler for the `NewInspector` event.
When the user creates a new mail message, this event handler adds text to the subject line and body of the message.

```
Private Sub inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector) Handles inspectors.NewInspector
    Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(Inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
    If Not (mailItem Is Nothing) Then 
        If mailItem.EntryID Is Nothing Then
            mailItem.Subject = "This text was added by using code"
            mailItem.Body = "This text was added by using code" 
        End If 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases accessing the MailItem in the NewInspector event is too early. I.e. you will not get a valid MailItem object. That's why I'd recommend waiting for the first [Activate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865363(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Inspector class.

You may find the [Developing an Inspector Wrapper for Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973716(v=office.14).aspx) article in MSDN helpful.

Comment: Good advice. Depends on what you're trying to do -and when-. `Activate` event occurs when an inspector becomes the active window whereas accessing the `MailItem` in the `NewInspector` event occurs before that.

Comment: It seems you have never faced with such issues before. Never access the MailItem object in the first NewInspector event.